# display inline not working for me

Tags: css

Hello all I have this script and I want, that this image was in one line and not brake other line but my code not work well please help me 
html

```
<div class="history_slider">
  <img src="img/pic/red-bull.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/pic/red-bull.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/pic/red-bull.jpg"/>
  <img src="img/pic/red-bull.jpg"/>         
</div>
```

css

```
.history_slider{
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    outline:1px solid #d6d7db;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.history_slider img{
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:125px;
    margin-right:125px;
    display:inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: I want like this]
I want like this

Comment: I can't see any script. Just HTML markup and CSS styles.

Comment: not exceed `margin-left:125px;`.`.history_slider{
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    height:180px;
 outline:1px solid #d6d7db;
    overflow-x:scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
.history_slider img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:25px;
    display:inline;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `white-space: nowrap;` declaration from the `.history_slider img` to the `.history_slider` selector. And maybe you have to adjust the widths, because they don't seem to add up/fit.

Furthermore, it seems like you could do with a beginner's course, because these really are very basic matters. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20beginners%20tutorial) contains links to such tutorials, from which you should make your own choice, depending on your learning style (text, text plus live examples, video, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/2p348Lep/

If you wish to have different images in one line, make sure they would not exceed the width of the div. In your case the div is 900px while the image is 700px.

```
.history_slider img{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```